# I want to make elements on my webpage stacked on top of eachother

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, position

I have a bunch of select elements that I need on top of each other (I do a bit of hiding/un-hiding to get what I need). My issue now is that the default HTML padding is making them all placed next to eachtoher. With CSS, how do I set the position of them to all be the same? This is what I tried but nothing happened on my page:

```css
select{
    right: 539.703125;
    top: 76; /* I got these values from the first select element (the only one in the right place)*/
    width: 146;
    height: 19;
}
```

Comment: you want same  width,height for each element?

Comment: @KareemDabbeet yes

Comment: I think I got what you want, I've just added  a new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set exact width for all `select` elements

Try this:

```css
select { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
 <select name="test1">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="test2">
        <option value="1">option 1123</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
        <option value="3">option 3</option>
      </select>
    
      <select name="test3">
          <option value="1">option 1223131</option>
          <option value="2">option 2</option>
          <option value="3">option 3</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To stack them on top of eachother on the z-axis `position: absolute;` for all elements. Then each element can be adjusted on the z-index `z-index: 0;` `z-index: 1;` to order them on the z-index.

Comment: It doesn't. Doing that causes them to all be lined up (same on the x axis, not the y though). I need them to all be in the exact same spot.

Comment: So you mean stack on top of eachother on the z-axis?

Comment: yeah. I just want them to be in the exact same spot.

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for. Edited the original answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want the directly on top of eachother, set all of the stacked elements to `position:absolute;` from there set `z-index:[number]` but replace number with whatever number you feel like, the smallest index will be on the bottom and the highest will be on top. From there just use top, left, right, and bottom to position the stack where you want